# Finding UI elements in React JS from HTML dev tools

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

TL;DR: need to find UI element from website on React JS code

Basically I'm working on a project where I need to put id tags on certain ui elements in a website. The code is written in React JS but there are a lot of pages and I cannot find which one each ui element is in. Is there a way that I can use chrome dev tools while on the website to find what page the code is for each specific ui element?

(Sorry if the terminology is wrong/confusing, I'm new to coding)

Comment: install react devtools extension on the browser

Comment: As stated in the comment above, try [React Dev Tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools) it allows you to see the components in the DOM. Otherwise, use common sense, I'm sure your IDE has a SEARCH function, use the dev tools to look for the current class or ID on the divs and look for these in the code. Adding a "test" class to the component you think is the right one can help you make sure you're in the right spot. This is an example why sometimes using naming conventions and good structure can sense make a great difference in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not ok if I understand what you want, but if you wanna to get UI elements that exists inside React Component, I suggest you to use React Dev Tools:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools

If you want more help, please share a code snippet to try to help you more